# Will VimService be supported for future SDK Release?

Tags: vmware, esxi, vsphere, esx, performance-monitor

We are planning to develop an application for monitoring the performance counters from various ESX servers. The two options available are vimService and esxtop. Esxtop may cause extra CPU consumption at the ESX server being monitored (as mentioned [here](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vcli/vcli501/vsp5_501_vcli_relnotes.html)). But we also doubt in using vimservice as we are not sure if vimservice will be available with future releases of SDK. As vsphere client may not exist from further release. We tried to search if vimservice will be removed from future SDK release, but couldn't anything useful. Kindly update the future plans with vimservice SDK.

Also to monitor the ESX performance counters, is there a better way other than esxtop and vimservice. Please clarify.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vSphere API](https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2012/02/introduction-to-the-vsphere-api-part-1.html) for that. VMWare's vSphere client uses the same API, so you can be sure that if will be supported